# stream_socket_client time out

Tags: php, sockets, stream-socket-client

I'm trying to debug the PHP function [stream_socket_client](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php) but I don't really know how. This is the code that I'm having trouble with:

```
        $this->socket = @stream_socket_client(
            $remote, $errno, $errstr,
            $this->request->getConfig('connect_timeout'),
            STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context
        );
        if (!$this->socket) {
            throw new HTTP_Request2_ConnectionException(
                "Unable to connect to {$remote}. Error: {$errstr}",
                0, $errno
            );
        }
```

The exception is thrown and the error reads "Unable to connect to tcp://www.dropbox.com:80. Error: Connection timed out". This code comes from a very popular [Wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-backup-to-dropbox/) that's been well tested. The server I'm working on has some quirks, e.g. I'm allowed to upload or remove files via PHP etc. so I'm wondering if there are any PHP settings that could prevent stream_socket_client from working and how I can check what those settings are for my server.

Comment: Perhaps the server has outgoing http connections blocked? Firewall issue? Do you have shell access to the server? try doing a "telnet www.dropbox.com:80" at the command line and see if that connects. If not, then it's not a PHP problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have shell access. This isn't my server, I'm merely installing something for somebody and although it's not on a web hotel, the setup is like that with control panel and everything...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to check `allow_url_fopen`.

> This option enables the URL-aware fopen wrappers that enable accessing URL object like files.

See: https://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php

Comment: According to phpinfo, allow_url_fopen is "on."

Comment: Ok. Could you try fsockopen and check errors? Maybe this error isn't related to streams and related to firewall or something else.

Comment: Alright, for example fsockopen( 'www.google.com', 80 ); doesn't seem to work. Also connection time out, as well as for dropbox.com naturally. I don't know what this means though? What in my hosting environment do I need to change?

Comment: What type of hosting do you use?

Comment: There are two causes: 1. DNS problem 2. hoster doesn't allow to make external requests.

Comment: I'll continue this discussion with my host then, thank you very much for your help.